# AngularJS Multiple ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use ng-repeat for two different item at the same time.
I mean,    **ng-repeat="mylist1 in list1 && mylist2 in list2"**

I need to use repeat for list1 and list2.

How can i use ng-repeat for more than one item?

Comment: Assuming they're both the same length, you could always access the corresponding `mylist2` item via `mylist2[$index]`

Comment: Do you want them to repeat at the same time or do you want them to join together and repeat as one variable? what i mean is do you want ng-repeat="mylist1 in list1 && mylist2 in list2" or ng-repeat="mylist in list1 and list2"?

Comment: how can i use $index?can you explain more?

Comment: i want to repeat at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off creating a combined list. For example (in your controller)

```
$scope.lists = list1.map(function(item, i) {
    return {
        item1: item,
        item2: list2[i] || null
    };
});
```

Then you can just iterate over this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in lists">
    <p>list1 item: {{ item.item1 }}</p>
    <p>list2 item: {{ item.item2 }}</p>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use `$index` to reference the corresponding item in `list2`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item1 in list1" ng-init="item2 = list2[$index]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function in the controller to concat them:

```
$scope.mergeLists = function (arr1, arr2) {
     return arr1.concat(arr2);
}
```

Then you have:

```
<div ng-repeat="mylist1 in mergeLists(list1, list2)">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13861/)

Comment: Won't this just make one long list?

Comment: @Phil It will, and this solves the issue if you want to iterate over the items list by list, and not intertwined.

Comment: I get the feeling OP wants them intertwined

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have two lists as follows:

```
mylist1=[1,2,3,4,5]
mylist2=[6,7,8,9,0]
```

and you want to iterate over them such that the resulting elements are

```
[[1,6,], [2,7], [3,8], [4,9], [5,0]]
```

I'd suggest you take a look at [zip](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) in lodash.js (or underscore.js) - Amazing library of functions that HELP you comb and keep all your hair.

```
Example:
_.zip(['fred', 'barney'], [30, 40], [true, false]);
// → [['fred', 30, true], ['barney', 40, false]]
```

and in this case:

```
mergedLists = _.zip(mylist1, mylist2)
ng-repeat="item in mergedLists"
```

In your application js file, you can assign the result of zipping the two lists, then use ng-repeat to iterate over the values in the list.  Note that each item in the list is also a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `ng-init`

```
<div ng-repeat="mylist1 in list1" ng-init="i=0;lst2 = list2[i++]">
```

Now you can use lst2